# multiSelect is not working for comboBox in EXTJS 3.2.1

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, extjs, extjs3

I am using Ext JS 3.2.1 version.

I am using one combo box where I can select a single value but now I want to select multiple values from that combo box. After researching about combo boxes, I had got one property 'multiSelect' which need to be set to 'true'. But this property is supporting only for versions above 4.0.

My code is:

```
items: [
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    fieldLabel: 'E-Mail Address11',
    id: 'scheduleEmails',
    name: 'email',
    mode: 'local',
    vtype: 'multiEmail',
    allowBlank: false,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    forceSelection: true,
    editable: true,
    enableShiftSelect: true,
    multiSelect: true,
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id',
    store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        fields: ['name', 'id'],
        data: [
            { name: 'Sunday@gmail.com', id: 'sunday' },
            { name: 'Monday@gmail.com', id: 'monday' },
            { name: 'Tuesday@gmail.com', id: 'tuesday' },
            { name: 'Wednesday@gmail.com', id: 'wednesday' },
            { name: 'Thursday@gmail.com', id: 'thursday' },
            { name: 'Friday@gmail.com', id: 'friday' },
            { name: 'Saturday@gmail.com', id: 'saturday' }
        ]})
}]
```

Comment: Please do not add "please help me" or other forms of pleading, either to your questions or in comments. Readers are **volunteers** who are here at their leisure, and answers are not guaranteed. It is a good idea to carry on researching your problem once it is posted, or if you really have nothing else to try, work on something else.

Comment: I can give you on idea here. For Multiselect combobox in EXTJS 3 you have to write your own class.  with extend to `Ext.form.ComboBox` and in that  you create a separate input field in dom which can separate input with some dilimter.